# custom advertise is not working with jwplayer

Tags: php, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I am working with custom advertise in jwplayer, but it is not working for me,
Here is my code,

(1) customad.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/DkwOvSfA.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">Loading the player...</div>
<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer('container');
playerInstance.setup({
    file: 'https://testvideoout.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/Streaming/mp4_Videos_29_1446555606635',
    image: "https://testvideoout.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/Thumb/Thumb_Videos_29_1446555606635_00001.png",
    primary: 'flash',
    type: "mp4",
    advertising: {
          client: 'vast',
          tag: 'advertise.xml',
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(2)advertise.xml

```
<VAST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast3_draft.xsd">
    <Ad id="midroll-1" sequence="1">
        <InLine>
            <AdSystem version="2.0">JW Player</AdSystem>
            <AdTitle>Static Tag</AdTitle>
            <Error>
http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif?err=[ERRORCODE]
</Error>
            <Impression>http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Impression>
            <Creatives>
                <Creative sequence="1">
                    <Linear skipoffset="00:00:03">
                        <Duration>00:00:30</Duration>
                        <TrackingEvents>
                            <Tracking event="start">http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="firstQuartile">http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="midpoint">http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="thirdQuartile">http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="complete">http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="pause">http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="mute">http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="fullscreen">http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</Tracking>
                        </TrackingEvents>
                        <VideoClicks>
                            <ClickThrough>http://www.jwplayer.com</ClickThrough>
                            <ClickTracking>http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/pixel.gif</ClickTracking>
                        </VideoClicks>
                        <MediaFiles>
                            <MediaFile id="1" delivery="progressive" type="video/mp4" bitrate="400" width="640" height="360">
http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/jwplayer-30s.mp4
</MediaFile>
                        </MediaFiles>
                    </Linear>
                </Creative>
                <Creative>
                    <CompanionAds>
                        <Companion id="1" width="300" height="250">
                            <StaticResource creativeType="image/jpg">
http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/jwplayer-rectangle.jpg
</StaticResource>
                            <CompanionClickThrough>http://www.jwplayer.com</CompanionClickThrough>
                        </Companion>
                        <Companion id="2" width="728" height="90">
                            <StaticResource creativeType="image/jpg">
http://demo.jwplayer.com/static-tag/jwplayer-leaderboard.jpg
</StaticResource>
                            <CompanionClickThrough>http://www.jwplayer.com</CompanionClickThrough>
                        </Companion>
                    </CompanionAds>
                </Creative>
            </Creatives>
        </InLine>
    </Ad>
</VAST>
```

Can anyone please look in it and tell me whats wrong in it, I tried lot but is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I copy/pasted your code into files advertise.htm and advertise.xml, and placed them in the same place on a test server, and didn't see any problems.

Be sure you are working remotely, and not editing them files on your local system. You may run into protocol issues:

> GET file://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/7.2.3/jwplayer.flash.swf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/user/Desktop/so.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

If this doesn't help, please edit your question with more information. Add a better description, and any information from the console which looks interesting.